# Extra lines in terminal output after upgrading to 18.10

Tags: command-line, upgrade

After upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10 I began to see such lines. What's wrong?

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
2018/10/25 10:02:58.175716 main.go:158: argument "abort"'s "<смена ID>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.175829 main.go:158: argument "ack"'s "<файл подтверждения>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.176064 main.go:158: argument "tasks"'s "<смена ID>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.176142 main.go:158: argument "create-key"'s "<имя ключа>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.176210 main.go:158: argument "create-user"'s "<отослать>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.176277 main.go:158: argument "delete-key"'s "<имя ключа>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.176408 main.go:158: argument "export-key"'s "<имя ключа>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.176485 main.go:158: argument "find"'s "<запрос>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.176567 main.go:158: argument "get"'s "<ключ>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.176684 main.go:158: argument "interface"'s "<интерфейс>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.176773 main.go:158: argument "known"'s "<тип подтверждения>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.176798 main.go:158: argument "known"'s "<фильт заголовков>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.176889 main.go:158: argument "login"'s "<отослать>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.176992 main.go:158: argument "prepare-image"'s "<модель подтверждения>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.177020 main.go:158: argument "prepare-image"'s "<корневая директория>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.177139 main.go:158: argument "services"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.177206 main.go:158: argument "logs"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.177261 main.go:158: argument "start"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.177334 main.go:158: argument "stop"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.177399 main.go:158: argument "restart"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.177467 main.go:158: argument "set"'s "<конфигурационное значение>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.177560 main.go:158: argument "sign-build"'s "<имя файла>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.177963 main.go:158: argument "wait"'s "<ключ>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.178017 main.go:158: argument "watch"'s "<смена ID>s" should be wrapped in <>s
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251189 main.go:158: argument "abort"'s "<смена ID>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251259 main.go:158: argument "ack"'s "<файл подтверждения>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251388 main.go:158: argument "tasks"'s "<смена ID>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251423 main.go:158: argument "create-key"'s "<имя ключа>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251468 main.go:158: argument "create-user"'s "<отослать>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251492 main.go:158: argument "delete-key"'s "<имя ключа>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251563 main.go:158: argument "export-key"'s "<имя ключа>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251605 main.go:158: argument "find"'s "<запрос>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251641 main.go:158: argument "get"'s "<ключ>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251711 main.go:158: argument "interface"'s "<интерфейс>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251749 main.go:158: argument "known"'s "<тип подтверждения>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251766 main.go:158: argument "known"'s "<фильт заголовков>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251817 main.go:158: argument "login"'s "<отослать>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251884 main.go:158: argument "prepare-image"'s "<модель подтверждения>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251900 main.go:158: argument "prepare-image"'s "<корневая директория>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251963 main.go:158: argument "services"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.251999 main.go:158: argument "logs"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.252032 main.go:158: argument "start"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.252077 main.go:158: argument "stop"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.252110 main.go:158: argument "restart"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.252156 main.go:158: argument "set"'s "<конфигурационное значение>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.252207 main.go:158: argument "sign-build"'s "<имя файла>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.252453 main.go:158: argument "wait"'s "<ключ>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/10/25 10:02:58.252484 main.go:158: argument "watch"'s "<смена ID>s" should be wrapped in <>s
```

Comment: Most people on this site don't speak Russian, so please translate the error messages, or run the command again with `LANG=C` prefixed, i.e. `LANG=C sudo apt autoremove`, which will get an English translation.

Comment: With this LANG=C this output is gone away. Seems like apt fails with tranlations

Answer (score 1):

Best way to put locale to `/etc/default/locale` e.g.:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

check changes with `cat /etc/default/locale`

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MESSAGES=C
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

or edit bash profiale `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Got same output from apt on Ubuntu-Mate 18.10. Adding "LANG=C" prefix solves this for me too. So, here's a workaround.

Rename apt and apt-get binaries:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo mv apt apt_orig
sudo mv apt-get apt-get_orig
```

Create a script "apt" (`sudo nano apt`) with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
LANG=C apt_orig $*
```

and `sudo nano apt-get`:

```
#!/bin/bash
LANG=C apt-get_orig $*
```

Then make them executable:

```
sudo chmod +x apt apt-get
```

---

These will probably be overwritten when the apt and apt-get packages are updated. Will hope that next update will fix the issue :) Maybe someone can offer a more persistant solution.